# How to combine different pollutants into a common measure?

Tags: climate-change

I'm examining several pollutant variables -- like CO2, lead, NOX etc -- and wondering how I can weight them appropriately to have some kind of comparability. Not all pollutants are equally bad for the environment and some have only local rather than global impacts.

Could one transfer a ton of pollutant X and pollutant Y into a common comparison of say implied mortality costs, CO2 footprint equivalents?

is there a literature on this, widely used methods?

Comment: Interesting question, and of some relevance to economics via your suggestion re implied mortality costs.  Overall however it appears more suitable for Earth Science SE which, unlike Economics SE, does have a tag for pollution.

Comment: many thanks Adam. I'll also post it there. Although the question was motivated by economic topics.